# Nested static class cannot return its static fields

Tags: java, oop

I need to create new warrior, assign name, and get his description with function specified in GameCahracter class. When I am trying to run - it stops on `weapon.type ; // <<Exception`  showing that `weapon=null`. Why? As far as I know warrior constructor assigned to variable `weapon` a link to new Weapon.Sword. Then using variable weapon I should be able to access it's field `type`. What is wrong here?

---

```
abstract class GameCahracter{
    public String name;
    public String type;
    public Weapon weapon; 
    public int hitPoints;

    public String getDescription(){
        return  name + "; " + 
        type + "; "  + 
        hitPoints + " hp; " + 

        weapon.type ; // << Exception
    }

    public static class Warrior extends Player{
        public Warrior() {
            type = "Warrior";
            hitPoints = 100;
            Weapon.Sword weapon = new Weapon.Sword(); 
    }
}
```

---

```
abstract class Player extends GameCahracter {

}
```

---

```
 abstract class Weapon {
    public int damage;
    public String type = "default";

    public int getDamage(){
        return this.damage;
    }

    public static class Sword extends Weapon{

        public Sword() {

            String type = "Sword";
            int damage = 10; 
        }

    }
}
```

---

```
GameCahracter.Warrior wr = new GameCahracter.Warrior();     
wr.setName("Joe");
System.out.println( wr.getDescription());
```

---

EDIT1

For some reason I'm having `default` string when printing out `weapon.type`. Why? How can I get `type`to be `Sword`?

Comment: You know that `Character` is not spelled `Cahracter` right?

Comment: @Truth:  At least it's consistent.  That counts more as far as the compiler is concerned.

Comment: Thanks, I know how Character is spelled. =) The question is why *weapon* is *null*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this moment your constructor leave `weapon` field to `null`. Simply creates a `Sword` instance that is garbaged once is out of the scope.

So change the line

```
Weapon.Sword weapon = new Weapon.Sword();
```

in your `Warrior` constructor with

```
weapon = new Weapon.Sword();
```

or better with

```
this.weapon = new Weapon.Sword();
```

and you do a similar error in `Sword` constructor when you write

```
String type = "Sword";
int damage = 10;
```

change them with

```
this.type = "Sword";
this.damage = 10;
```

Comment: It worked. But for some reason I'm having *default* string when printing *weapon.type*. Why? How can i get *type* string *Sword*?

Comment: In the answer I write you how to fix that problem too :D

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is in this line :

```
Weapon.Sword weapon = new Weapon.Sword();
```

You shadow your member variable with a local one.

Replace it with :

```
this.weapon = new Weapon.Sword();
```

Answer (score 1):

You would get an exception at that line because the variable `weapon` in your instance of `GameCahracter` is null. There is no code anywhere that sets it. The code in the `Warrior` constructor sets the value of a new local variable, not the member variable from the class.